# Docker Compose: How to configure a Multi-Stage Docker image split into multiple Dockerfiles?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 3 Dockerfiles

**./Dockerfile**

```
FROM rust:1.43.1
WORKDIR /usr/src/hiro
COPY . .
RUN cargo build
```

**./Dockerfile.master**

```
FROM me/base
RUN chmod +x ./target/debug/hiro
CMD [ "./target/debug/hiro", "--master", "-p", "${PORT}" ]
```

**./Dockerfile.worker**

```
FROM me/base
RUN chmod +x ./target/debug/hiro
CMD [ "./target/debug/hiro", "--worker", "-p", "${PORT}" ]
```

#### Build (without Docker Compose)

```
docker build -t me/base -f Dockerfile .
```

and then,

```
docker build -t me/master -f Dockerfile.master .
```

```
docker build -t me/worker -f Dockerfile.worker .
```

I'm creating both `master` and `worker`, from the same base image that does the hard work of compiling source code. Somewhat like what explained in this Stackoverflow question: [Docker Multi-Stage: How to split up into multiple Dockerfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659993/docker-multi-stage-how-to-split-up-into-multiple-dockerfiles)

#### Question

How can I configure my docker-compose.yml to build both images from the same base image?

Comment: BTW, I found an answer to my question [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101932/9406420](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53101932/9406420)

Answer (score 1):

If the *only* thing that's different between the two images is the `CMD`, that's easy to override in the `docker-compose.yml`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  master:
    build: . # uses the base Dockerfile
    command: ./target/debug/hiro --master --port 12345
  worker:
    build: .
    command: ./target/debug/hiro --worker --port 12345
```

The other thing that's easy to customize this way is per-invocation environment variables.  Note, though, that this won't go through and rebuild the image with different variables; it will only launch the final `CMD` with a different environment.

Your question shows plain `docker build` commands; with plain `docker run` anything after the image name is similarly interpreted as the command to run.

```
docker run ... me/base \
  ./target/debug/hiro --worker --port 12345
```

(If you're looking for other examples of this, this is especially common in Python Django/Celery applications.  The "main" application is a Django-based Web server, but it shares most of its source tree with a Celery task runner, and you launch the Celery worker with the same image but a different command.)