# Docker can't pull local built image in builder pattern

Tags: docker, pnpm, turborepo

I'm trying to setup a build flow in my monorepo with pnpm and turbo.

My goal is to have a structure like this:

```
apps/
    web/
       Dockerfile
    api/
       Dockerfile
Dockerfile
package.json
pnpm-lock.yaml
turbo.json
```

Where the root Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:18-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Prerequisites
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
RUN npm install -g pnpm@7.16.0

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY package.json ./
COPY pnpm*.yaml ./
COPY .npmrc ./
RUN pnpm fetch

# Set CI to true to disable lefthook hooks
ENV CI=true

# Copy all other files
COPY . ./
```

And then the /api Dockerfile looks like this (based on [this example](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/deploying-with-docker)):

```
FROM me/base as base

FROM node:18-alpine as api-builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Prerequisites
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
RUN npm install -g turbo

COPY --from=base /usr/src/app /usr/src/app/
RUN turbo prune --scope=api --docker


FROM node:18-alpine as api-installer
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Prerequisites
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
RUN npm install -g pnpm@7.16.0

COPY --from=api-builder /usr/src/app/out/json ./
COPY --from=api-builder /usr/src/app/pnpm-lock.yaml ./pnpm-lock.json
RUN pnpm install --filter=api --offline

COPY --from=api-builder /usr/src/app/out/full .
COPY --from=api-builder /usr/src/app/turbo.json ./turbo.json


FROM node:18-alpine as api-runner
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 runner
USER runner

COPY --from=api-installer /app/apps/api/package.json .

COPY --from=api-installer --chown=runner:nodejs /app/apps/api/build ./

ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "apps/api/build/server.js" ]
```

I start with building the base image like this:

`docker build . -t me/base`

And I double checked the image is effectively build (`docker image ls`).

Next, I try to run the Dockerfile inside `/apps/api`

But there it fails with:

```
[+] Building 0.7s (4/4) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.08kB                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/me/base:latest                                                                                                                                                          0.6s
 => CANCELED [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine                                                                                                                                                   0.6s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/me/base:latest:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
```

I got my inspiration from [Docker Multi-Stage: How to split up into multiple Dockerfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659993/docker-multi-stage-how-to-split-up-into-multiple-dockerfiles)

How can I make sure it doesn't pull from `docker.io` but from my local built image instead?

NOTE: I know there can be some optimizations but as a first version I first want to have this setup working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my issue here was that I had to use `--platform=linux/amd64` in the base image to make sure the `prisma` dependency still worked.

This means that I also have to use this in the followup images, because otherwise it can't find the local (then ARM64 since I'm on a m1 mac) image.

Comment: Did you get this to work? I'm struggling with the same issue at the moment with pnpm.

Comment: For me it worked to have `--platform=linux/amd64` in every image